# Retrieve the *real* exception thrown from a method reflectively invoked

Tags: java, reflection

Say I have a method foo() declared below.

```
public class Foo
{
    public static void foo() {throw new UnsupportedOperationException();}
}
```

Then I have code that invoked the method using reflection:

```
Foo.class.getMethod("foo").invoke();
```

This would throw `InvocationTargetException` rather than the `UnsupportedOperationException` that is actually thrown in the method.

How do I retrieve the *real* exception (ie., the UnsupportedOperationException) with Java's reflection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The javadoc for `InvocationTargetException` states

> InvocationTargetException is a checked exception that wraps an
>   exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor.

Just call `InvocationTargetException#getCause()` to get the wrapped exception (or `getTargetException()` if you want to be old-school).

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that `InvocationTargetException` due to refection invocation. Handle that `Exception` too.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
  // do your invoke
}

catch ( InvocationTargetException e)
{
     try
     {
           throw e.getCause ( ) ;
     }
     catch ( IllegalArgumentException e )
     {
           // method exception
     }
     catch ( NullPointerException e )
     {
            //method exception
     }
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html